# JBoss EAP 6.x - PolicyContext.getContext remains null

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jaas, java-security

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4 for my enterprise app and I'm a little stuck when I attempt to retrieve the active subject.

Of course, the user would need to authenticate, which goes through the following code snippet

```
LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("CONTEXTNAME", callbackHandler);
loginContext.login();
return loginContext.getSubject();
```

That works just fine (and the subject is filled in), however the problem lies when I try to retrieve the subject at a later point in the execution ...

`final Subject subject = (Subject)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");`

... where `subject` remains null!

What am I missing??

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

Thanks to the following article on [how to introduce the security manager on JBoss EAP 6.4](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Security_Guide/Run_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_Within_the_Java_Security_Manager.html).

The problem was that the security manager had to be configured in JBoss. You need to open the standalone.conf (or standalone.conf.bat), uncomment and add the following:

```
rem # Uncomment this to run with a security manager enabled
set "SECMGR=true"

rem # Using == when setting -Djava.security.policy specifies that the security manager 
rem # will use only the specified policy file. Using = specifies that the security 
rem # manager will use the specified policy combined with the policy set in the policy.url 
rem # section of JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security.
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.policy==%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\server.policy"
```

That would enable the security manager and make it point to a custom server.policy, which I have a sample of below:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

That would give all permissions to any modules to operate. Of course, you'll need to edit the policy file if you want to tighten up the security.

Retrieving the `Subject` is also easy:

```
Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
```

That's it! I hope it'll work for you guys as well.

Comment: The Java Security Manager shouldn't be related to the Subject retrieval.  I've tried both ways in a servlet. My tests suggests following. The JACC way (PolicyContext) works correctly. The JAAS way (Subject.getSubject()) returns null.